# Problems with my Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

***CLARIFICATION***

Looking at the comments, everyone says I can just SOP the Array-list. Yes, I know I can print out the Array-list, but the problem is is that with 500+ different arrays, I can't sort them, I can't use them, and I'm not sure what 'method' to use to combine them. I know that I was creating the for loop, I was making whatever much bdaynames.length is ... **500 different array-list's.**

I was thinking if I was able to create an array, I would be able to get all the values in the Array-list and be able to sort them. It isn't working because it's getting bdaynames.length was and sorting those out.

Here:

```
 //gets 3 dates from database ... parse ints ... gets difference in days ... prints out
  [-15]
  [-15]
  [-15]
  [-15]
  [-15]
  [12]
  [12]
  [12]
  [12]
  [12] 
  [19]
  [19]
  [19]
  [19]
  [19]
  //how can i put all of these numbers in ONE data-structure, NOT 15
```

Originally, I was hoping that once I created the Array-list I would be able to save the values like this! (That is what a Array-list is 'for' right?)

```
  [-15,-15,-15,-15,-15, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19]
  ...I would sort these values and the same would come out, etc, etc
```

**ACTUAL EDIT**

So I said to my clever self, we can simplify the problem by just putting this into a array. We already declared how many values we want, we can sort them out, the problem is solved. Long story short, while a thank you to the people who reminded me how to SOP a array, when I sorted it out, it was only sorting out the individual list's, not the array as the whole (I think). Sorry if I was unclear. Here is the actual output.

Here is the code that you guys need to look at (In case I did it wrong):

```
       Integer[] myArray = Intlist.toArray(new Integer[Intlist.size()]);
                for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
                    Arrays.sort(myArray);
                    System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
                }
```

THE WRONG OUTPUT (This is also to be sorted also)

```
 C:\Users\owner\Desktop\Website(Update Here!)\webs\developer\My R & D\EX 
 TRA\For Loop Testing>java -cp ; starter
 What is the month right now? 9
 What is today day? 17
 What is the year today? 2017
 39 39 39 39 39 -60 -60 -60 -60 -60 55 55 55 55 55 11 11 11 11 11 27 27 27 
 27 27 -239 -239 -239 -239 -239 -122 -122 -122 -122 -122 42 42 42 42 42 -37 
 -37 -37 -37 -37 -142 -142 -142 -142 -142 -103 -103 -103 -103 -103 -256 -256 
 -256 -256 -256 -13 -13 -13 -13 -13 3 3 3 3 3 22 22 22 22 22 51 51 51 51 51 
 -238 -238 -238 -238 -238 -74 -74 -74 -74 -74 25 25 25 25 25 92 92 92 92 92 
 -129 -129 -129 -129 -129 -124 -124 -124 -124 -124 -164 -164 -164 -164 -164 
 -103 -103 -103 -103 -103 13 13 13 13 13 59 59 59 59 59 29 29 29 29 29 8 8 8 
 8 8 -89 -89 -89 -89 -89 -45 -45 -45 -45 -45 -199 -199 -199 -199 -199 -213 
 -213 -213 -213 -213 -202 -202 -202 -202 -202 -121 -121 -121 -121 -121 -234 
 -234 -234 -234 -234 41 41 41 41 41 -160 -160 -160 -160 -160 -183 -183 -183 
 -183 -183 -136 -136 -136 -136 -136 -47 -47 -47 -47 -47 -179 -179 -179 -179 
 -179 -25 -25 -25 -25 -25 34 34 34 34 34 19 19 19 19 19 90 90 90 90 90 95 95 
 95 95 95 54 54 54 54 54 -38 -38 -38 -38 -38 -136 -136 -136 -136 -136 -232 
-232 -232 -232 -232 -93 -93 -93 -93 -93 -124 -124 -124 -124 -124 -42 -42 -42 
-42 -42 -178 -178 -178 -178 -178 -214 -214 -214 -214 -214 82 82 82 82 82 
-259 -259 -259 -259 -259 61 61 61 61 61 -257 -257 -257 -257 -257 -55 -55 -55 
-55 -55 -187 -187 -187 -187 -187 -248 -248 -248 -248 -248 -28 -28 -28 -28 
-28 95 95 95 95 95 -186 -186 -186 -186 -186 -234 -234 -234 -234 -234 -95 -95 
-95 -95 -95 -159 -159 -159 -159 -159 9 9 9 9 9 6 6 6 6 6 -18 -18 -18 -18 -18 
-198 -198 -198 -198 -198 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 94 94 94 94 94 -204 -204 -204 
-204 -204 -77 -77 -77 -77 -77 58 58 58 58 58 -214 -214 -214 -214 -214 -56 
-56 -56 -56 -56 -108 -108 -108 -108 -108 -175 -175 -175 -175 -175 -205 -205 
-205 -205 -205 80 80 80 80 80 -36 -36 -36 -36 -36 -127 -127 -127 -127 -127 
98 98 98 98 98 38 38 38 38 38 -92 -92 -92 -92 -92 83 83 83 83 83 -27 -27 -27 
-27 -27 -22 -22 -22 -22 -22 2 2 2 2 2 -132 -132 -132 -132 -132 -19 -19 -19 
-19 -19 -181 -181 -181 -181 -181 -36 -36 -36 -36 -36 -108 -108 -108 -108 
-108 -208 -208 -208 -208 -208 101 101 101 101 101 -164 -164 -164 -164 -164 
 57 57 57 57 57 15 15 15 15 15 -221 -221 -221 -221 -221 -102 -102 -102 -102 
-102 -36 -36 -36 -36 -36 -241 -241 -241 -241 -241 -155 -155 -155 -155 -155 
-80 -80 -80 -80 -80 4 4 4 4 4 58 58 58 58 58 -187 -187 -187 -187 -187 -27 
-27 -27 -27 -27 87 87 87 87 87 -67 -67 -67 -67 -67 -234 -234 -234 -234 -234 
-125 -125 -125 -125 -125 -143 -143 -143 -143 -143 -15 -15 -15 -15 -15 -200 
-200 -200 -200 -200 12 12 12 12 12 -102 -102 -102 -102 -102
C:\Users\owner\Desktop\Website(Update Here!)\webs\developer\My R & D\EX 
TRA\For Loop Testing>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Why not just `System.out.println(Intlist);`? Or, for that matter, `System.out.printf("[%d]%n", dayCount);`?

Comment: It creates a separate Arraylist every time when I do that, and I have 500 dates to sort out. That's really confusing, and I want to be able to have one data structure.

Comment: "It creates a separate Arraylist every time when I do that" It doesn't change the number of lists you create. You're *always* creating a new arraylist each time.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the Array's reference. Print a location in the array by indexing into it in a loop, e.g.:

```
for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
   System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```